# 401 on azure-devops-node-api with access token acquired from adal-node

Tags: azure-devops

This is an issue between adal-node and azure-devops-node-api.

After getting access token from adal-node, I apply it as API_TOKEN to call azure-devops-node-api's getWebApi, target api is azure devops(vsts)-https://dev.azure.com/{org}.

Unfortunatelly, it returns 401 error:

> Error: Error: Failed request: (401)
>       at RestClient. 
>       at Generator.next ()

Comment: Can you please share the code as well ?

Comment: According to your error message, it looks like there is a problem with the definition of authentication method in you code class, so could you please share your code?